# Acumatica API vs OData

Tags: acumatica

I am fairly new to Acumatica and was tasked with getting data out of Acumatica. There are two approaches with getting the data which I need; I can use the API (it's a straightforward table, no joins, etc.), or use OData to get the results of a Generic Inquiry. In this particular case it seems to be a pretty even choice. I can access both of these without any issue using Python.

There will be other requests for data in the future and I'm wondering what the big differences are between these approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The contract based API is tied to a screen (for defining the data contract), while OData is tied to a generic inquiry. If you already have a screen displaying the data you want, or if its in the default endpoint this is helpful, but if the data is not already being displayed on a screen it takes longer to create a whole screen than to whip up a GI.
2. Odata is read only, while the contract based API is read write.
3. The contract based API can invoke Action buttons

Otherwise, there is not a whole lot of difference in the end, both will suit your needs

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have access to the REST API which is not screen-based, as per the documentation which I received from Acumatica: 

"Contract-based REST API, which operates through the REST service with business logic objects and their properties and methods, which do not depend on Acumatica ERP forms. (In this context, contract-based means based on the object model the web service API provides.)"

The read/write doesn't apply to me at this time, though that is a big deal difference which I'll keep in mind.

Comment: Yes, poor choice of words, Acumatica ERP forms are used to define the data contract, but the API does not directly interact with the form when requests are handled. I edited my post

Comment: That looks better, thank you for clarifying. There seems to be an additional benefit of OData, as I was trying to get a field which wasn't displayed on the screen (an internal ID) and the default endpoint didn't seem to have it available.